# User IP in a Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I am building an ASP.NET application

If I run a website in a remote connection, what is the Ip that i get from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`? Is it the ip of my local network or the ip of the network that the remote computer is connected?

I need to detect the ip of the network that the user is actually using, not the one of the remote computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the ip of my local network or the ip of the network that the
>   remote computer is connected?

It will be the local IP.

> I need to detect the ip of the network that the user is actually using, not the one of the remote compute

Forget about this requirement. This information is not part of the HTTP protocol specification and is never sent to the server. You will need to either provide an input field on your site where you could ask the user to enter this information or have some desktop application running on the server that will be used to detect the IP of the remotely connected user and then launch the default web browser by navigating to your web application and passing it as a query string parameter for example.

Yet another possibility you may consider is to use some sort of ActiveX control that will retrieve this information. But we all know the constraints that come with ActiveX.

Comment: Ok this is my situation: I have built a website, in which users need to check-in their presence everyday. The site is published on the internet and they have to open it from any computer that is connected to my  network (if the local ip is the one i am using, i will mark them as present). THe problem is: if they connect from home to the computers in my network, and in the remote desktop connection they open the website, which is the ip the i get? the one of my network or the one of the network they use at home?

Comment: If they open the website from a remote desktop connection the website will get the IP address of the remote machine to which they are connected - the machine from which the web browser was started.

Comment: Are you sure? I just opened the website from a certain PC, then I connected via Remote Desktop to the server, opened the browser there and then opened the website. In both cases I got the same IP, even though it's not the same connection...

Comment: On which PC did you open the web browser? It is that IP address that you will get.

Comment: The second time, in the same PC i connected via Remote Desktop to another PC and in the Remote Desktop session I opened the browser. Why am I getting the same IP as if I didn't connect to the remote computer at all... Sorry for being a little slow. THnx

Comment: And by the way I got in both case 192.168.2.1... :/